# Show hash of files in a directory

Tags: powershell

What is the easiest way to list all files in a directory with their hashes?

I am trying to compare a list of files in a folder. The problem is that all the file sizes are the same but I need to ensure that their content are the same too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Powershell has a cmdlet named `Get-FileHash`. One can just do a `ls` and pipe the output to `GetFileHash`

eg. `ls | Get-FileHash`

You can also specify the hash algorithm by passing the -Algorithm parameter:

eg. `ls | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5`

Comment: How can list the file name in the output along with the Hash value and Algorithm?

Comment: You would need to pipe this to some select and use Split-Path to split the Path